# Search text in Bootstrap's SelectPicker using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to search text in dropdown and set it selected by text.Here is my control

HTML:

```
  <select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" id="area_location_id">
        <option value="" selected="">Select</option>
        <option value="17">Al Barsha</option>
       <option value="82">Al Furjan</option>
      <option value="4924">Al Garhoud</option>
      <option value="5787">Al Jadaf</option>
     <option value="5684">Al Mamzar</option
    </select>
```

Jquery:

```
 var mytxt = "Al Furjan";
("#area_location_id").find("option:contains('" + mytxt  + "')").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
});
$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('refresh');
$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('val', mytxt );
```

I am using bootstrap selectpicker. Can I use `contain:` in this code or does selectpicker have its own method?

**UPDATED:**

I tried with simple select control and it is working...Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZmEw/493/)

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: I want to show selected text based on my passing variable.In my above case i want it to show 'Al Furjan' selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need solution for the same situation,I resolved it like here

```
var userToSearchFor = "Jadaf";
$("#area_location_id").find("option:contains('" + userToSearchFor +"')")
.each(function ()   {
 $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
});

$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('val', userToSearchFor );
$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit changes to below answer.

```
var userToSearchFor = "text to search";
var selectedID;
$("#area_location_id").find("option:contains('" + userToSearchFor +"')")
    .each(function ()   {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
        selectedID = $(this).val();
});

$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('val', selectedID );
$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('refresh');
```

note that selectpickers value cannot be st by attr("selected", true)
also val can be set by option value not select text.